# How do I query a local datatable and return information to a datatable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to pass a query and existing datatable into a function. The function will query the passed datatable using the passed query and return the result.

Unfortunately, I am unable to return any data. I have posted my code below. Can anyone help me fix it? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
Public Function ExecQueryTest(Query As String, DT As DataTable) As DataTable

    Dim Result() As DataRow
    'initialize the table to have the same number of columns of the table that is passed into the function
    Dim LocalTable As DataTable = DT
    'initialize counting variables
    Dim x, y As Integer

    'use the select command to run a query and store the results in an array
    Result = DT.Select(Query)

   'remove all items from the localtable after initial formatting
    For x = 0 To LocalTable.Rows.Count - 1
        LocalTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    Next

    'for loop to iterate for the amount of rows stored in result
    For x = 0 To Result.GetUpperBound(0)
        'add each array row into the table 
        LocalTable.Rows.Add(Result(x))
    Next

    ExecQueryTest = LocalTable
End Function
```

If there is a better way to accomplish my goal, I don't mind starting from scratch. I just want to be able to handle dynamic tables, queries, and be able to return the information in a datatable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear a table with just

```
LocalTable.Clear()
```

instead of using that cycle, Also the results of your select can be directly converted to datatable using

```
LocalTable = Result.CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Dim LocalTable As DataTable = DT
```

That code does not do what you think it does. `DataTable` is a reference type, which means assigning `DT` to the `LocalTable` variable only *assigns a reference to the same object.* No new table is created, and nothing is copied. Therefore, *this later code also clears out the original table:*

```
'remove all items from the localtable after initial formatting
For x = 0 To LocalTable.Rows.Count - 1
    LocalTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
Next
```

Try this instead:

```
Public Function ExecQueryTest(Query As String, DT As DataTable) As DataTable
    ExecQueryTest = New DataTable() 'create new DataTable object to hold results
    For Each row As DataRow In DT.Select(Query)
        ExecQueryTest.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, True)
    Next
End Function
```

Though you may also need to clone each `DataRow` record.